# Adding a fade opacity to my Div scroll function?

Tags: javascript, css

I've managed to get div(s) to stick at the top offset by 64px on scroll but I also want the same div's opacity to fade to 0. I can't figure out how to add this? An example of what I have done so far.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".ComponentOne").css("top",Math.max(64,800-scrollTop));
});
```

Comment: add a `fade()` after the `.css()` selector

Comment: $(".ComponentOne").css("top",Math.max(64,800-scrollTop)).fade();

Answer (score 1):

> **Updated**

Try below code:

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var offsetTop = $('.ComponentOne').position().top;
  console.log(offsetTop);
  $(".ComponentOne").css("top", Math.max(64, 800 - scrollTop));
  if (offsetTop === 64) {
    $(".ComponentOne").css("opacity", "0");
  } else {
    $(".ComponentOne").css("opacity", "1");
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ComponentOne {
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it starts the fade to opacity 0 the moment you start scrolling rather than when "ComponentOne" reaches the scroll top position of 64px.

Comment: The behavior I looking to do is "ComponentOne" starts at a "top" position of 800px with "opacity" 0. User scrolls down and when "ComponentOne" reaches the "top" position of 64px is stays "fixed" and then fades to "opacity" 0.  If user scrolls up everything goes in reverse.

Comment: As me understand your question, I think you want this. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.ComponentOne{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background:pink;
    position:absolute;
    top:800px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

js

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var compTop = $('.ComponentOne').offset().top;

        var controllOpacity = 1400;

        if(scrollTop + 100 > compTop)
        {
            $(".ComponentOne").css("top","64px");
            $(".ComponentOne").css("position","fixed");
            $(".ComponentOne").css("opacity", ((scrollTop - 800)/(controllOpacity - 800)));

        }
        if(scrollTop < 800){
            $(".ComponentOne").css("top","800px");
            $(".ComponentOne").css("position","absolute");
            $(".ComponentOne").css("opacity", ((scrollTop - 800)/(controllOpacity - 800)));
        }

    });

});
```

Just adjust the value of controlOpacity variable according to you. It is used to control the range within which the div should fadeout completely. So if you lower it the div will fadeout quickly as you scoll and if you keep it large then div will fadeout slowly with scroll

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8u6yu0b/1/) for the example

Comment: Thanks but again same issue as above. Yeah I tried that but it starts the fade to opacity 0 the moment you start scrolling rather than when "ComponentOne" reaches the scroll top position of 64px. – Mark 9 mins ago   
     
The behavior I looking to do is "ComponentOne" starts at a "top" position of 800px with "opacity" 0. User scrolls down and when "ComponentOne" reaches the "top" position of 64px is stays "fixed" and then fades to "opacity" 0. If user scrolls up everything goes in reverse. – Mark 5 mins ago

Comment: check out the code i edited it. its working correctly for me. try it.

Comment: Thanks Raj. So close!  But how do I make the opacity be controlled by the scroll rather than just a 2 second transition fade out.

Comment: finally the div is fading with scrolling so please check it out.

Comment: unfortunately no. the opacity change happens immediately rather than starting when it reaches the fixed top position of 64px.